# How create a semi transparent control on a transparent form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

Hi
I love this application http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/downloads.asp

and I have written an app that puts buttons on a flowlayoutpanel which is all on a transparent form. hope that clear but if not let me know and I try again!

What I would like to do is make the buttons appear the same way the icons do when using the above application.

How do you do this??

This is a .Net4 classic forms app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a related link with sample code for your question.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/VistaButton.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this however this how to draw buttons, What I need is how to draw a frame-less semi transparent form...
Sorry if my question was not that clear.